# How to prevent Manager to approve his own Leave in Odoo?

Tags: odoo-8

how can I prevent Managers from approving their own leave requests?
I have added one ename field and function in holidays.py.

```
'ename':fields.many2one('res.users','Name',readonly=True),

def is_officer_employee(self,cr,uid,ids,ename,context=None):
        user_obj = self.pool.get('res.users')
        user_value = user_obj.browse(cr, uid, uid)

        for leave in self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context):
            if leave.ename.id == uid:
                raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning!'), _('Can not approve own Leave!'))
            else:
                return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state':'validate1', 'manager_id': False})
```

Now manager cant approve his own leave,only his manager can approve.Now after adding this above function code,validate button for second approval is not working.

Please provide some solution.
Thank You.

Comment: What you mean by validate for seccond approval?, what module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can below way to prevent the manager to approve its own leave :

first you must need to understand the below concept for hr.holidays model and its relation.

**employee_id :**

Each  Leave request having a one Employee to it

**parent_id (manager field) :**

Which is attached with the each Employee it means each employee having one manager.

**user_id :**

Each Employee attached with one related users which is helpful for make to access the Employee as user login.

It means if you want to access login for the each employee then the related user filed is too much important for us.

In your case basically no need to require to add `ename` field for each leave request.

so you can do some things like this :

```
for leave in self.browse(cr,uid,ids,context=context):
            if leave.employee_id.parent_id.user_id.id == uid:
                raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning!'), _('Can not approve own Leave!'))
            else:
                return self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state':'validate1', 'manager_id': False})
```

please add above code in your method action and check to validate that leave request.

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)